# I need to apply rotation to an onclick class. This is my current code. Any tips on how to change it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, rotation

This is my html for the onclick.

```
<div class="logo">
        <img src="images/exyl.jpg" class="nice-logo" id="rotator" onclick="rotation()">
      </div>
```

This is my javascript to initiate the function.

```
function rotation() {
  var button = document.getElementById('rotator');
  button.classList.toggle('class')
}
```

and this is the css I used.

```
.class {
  transform:rotate();
}
```

As most of you more experienced coders can tell, I'm doing this on a very beginner level. But any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. SO is for specific coding issues such as debugging help. Its not a reveiw for code plattform. Try Code Review instead:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rotate() function expects a degree parameter. If you wish to rotate say 90 degrees, the css should be:

```
transform: rotate(90deg)
```